# Не отображается изображение в VueCLI

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-cli

https://github.com/k1ok1/starwars/tree/second - Репозиторий на GitHub.

Проблема такая, я присвоил новые свойства к готову API внутри запроса Axios. Все свойства нормально присвоились. У меня есть компонент 'FilmsList'. Внутри него формируется список и в нем есть изображение, но по какой-то причине этот путь неверный, т.е. не видит изображение.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/1ra445p - как отображается список.
https://prnt.sc/1ra45zp - присвоение путей для изображений.
https://prnt.sc/1ra48gn - задание пути в vue-компоненте.
По первому скрину видно, что изображения не отображаются должным образом. Помогите исправить эту ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за помощь, я нашел решение, просто перенес папки с картинками в папку Public и все. Путь прописывали нормально)